# How to make auto-mounted USB drives accessible to other users

Tags: 14.04, mount, permissions, usb-drive

When a logged-in user attaches a USB drive, Ubuntu is auto-mounting the drive to `/media/MyUserName/[drive-label]`. That user can read/write to the drive.

I need to make that drive and any other future drive have read permission to all other users. I've tried doing `chmod 777` on `/media/MyuserName/`, but that doesn't seem to work. Other users can see the directories immediately in `/media/MyUserName/`, but not any deeper. Adding a recursive flag does nothing.

I've read about updating `fstab`, but I'm not exactly sure what to put as it seems to depend on where the usb drive actually gets added to in the file system, somewhere in `/dev/`.

What do I need to do here?